# How to alter default fill settings for geom_bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Greetings, I am trying to create a bar chart of the data posted below (referred to in my code as `topTwoTable`), disaggregated by group type. I've scanned through multiple online forums, as well as Hadley's website, and stuck when it comes to manually altering the fill color of the bars on the basis of treatment type.

Any thoughts?

Cheers, 
Aaron

Comment: Could someone edit this post to properly align the code?

Comment: Aaron, could you provide us with some sample data with dput(topTwoTable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to specify your colors with "scale_colour_manual"

http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_manual.html

I believe adding the following to the end of your current code should work.

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("light blue"," dark blue"))
```

Comment: actually, `scale_fill_manual` is the one you want (i.e. that changes the bar color to whatever you like).